# Does the Lotusscript if statement short circuit?

Tags: lotusscript

Quick one: Does anyone know if the Lotusscript [if statement](https://help.hcltechsw.com/dom_designer/11.0.1/basic/LSAZ_IF_THEN_ELSE_STATEMENT.html) [short circuits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)? Nothing appears to be written in the documentation.

E.g. if `doc.HasItem("MyField")` test is false, the `doc.MyField(0)=...` test is not performed.

```
if doc.HasItem("MyField") and doc.MyField(0)<>"" then ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The if statement in LotusScript definitvely doesn't short circuit. The complete statement is evaluated and then the decision is made. This sometimes is very annoying e.g when you want to do something like:

```
If doc.HasItem( "SomeNumber" ) and doc.GetItemValue( "SomeNumber" )(0) > 100 Then
```

This will throw a "Type mismatch" for documents that do not have the item "SomeNumber" as the comparision is made although the first statement is already false...

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember. But try it out!

```
Function p(x As String) as Boolean
  print x
  p = True
End Function

Sub test()
  If p("a") or p("b") Then
    p("c")
  End If
End Sub
```

If it doesn't print "b" then yes!

Comment: This code won't work... p = x will throw a "type mismatch"... it should be p = True instead